# embedded document with in embedded in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have at present

```
{
        "_id": "5aa50b19db6ed014a0239511",
        "exp_Comm_Inv_No": "10",
        "exp_Inv_id_1": {
            "_id": "5a9bfb013fbdb9107165b682",
            "exp_Inv_No": "21",
            "exp_Inv_Date": "2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
            "exp_Party_Name": "5a9bfaea3fbdb9107165b681",
            "currency_Name": {
                "_id": "5a1c1bfabea31d368632e7b4",
                "currency_Name": "GBP",
                "created_On": "2017-11-27T14:06:50.677Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "inv_Amt_Fc": 321,
            "fc_Rate": 23,
            "created_On": "2018-03-04T13:56:17.276Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
}
```

but I want this

```
{
        "_id": "5aa50b19db6ed014a0239511",
        "exp_Comm_Inv_No": "10",
        "exp_Inv_id_1": {
            "_id": "5a9bfb013fbdb9107165b682",
            "exp_Inv_No": "21",
            "exp_Inv_Date": "2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
            "exp_Party_Name": "5a9bfaea3fbdb9107165b681",
            "currency_Name": "GBP",
            "inv_Amt_Fc": 321,
            "fc_Rate": 23,
            "created_On": "2018-03-04T13:56:17.276Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use $project 
`$project{'currency_Name' : "$currency_Name.currency_Name" }`